# Debian owner permissions fail

Tags: debian

I have some problems with the correct permissions on my dedicated server. We have user1: `shelly`, user2: `shellycod4`, group: `shellycod4`.

```
# groups shelly
shelly : shelly shellycod4

# groups shellycod4
shellycod4 : shellycod4

root@:/home/shelly/cod4server/server# ls -l
insgesamt 28
-rw-r--r-- 1 shellycod4 shellycod4 24466 Jan 19 23:52 img.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 shellycod4 shellycod4 1757 Jan 19 23:52 unknown.png

# ls -ld /home/shelly/cod4server/server
drwxr-xr-x 3 shellycod4 shellycod4 4096 Jan 20 21:55 /home/shelly/cod4server/server
```

It says the user shelly has no permissions on the selected dir.
Could someone tell me where I failed?

Comment: You should include the command that fails with the error message it gives.  I think we'll probably also need `ls -ld /home/shelly/cod4server/server` to answer you precisely.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 3 shellycod4 shellycod4 4096 Jan 20 21:55 /home/shelly/cod4server/server  Well, modifying stuff or creating new stuff isnt working.

Comment: and ` ls -dl /home/shelly/cod4server/server /home/shelly/cod4server /home/shelly /home`

Comment: And show us what you tried to do, and what happened.

Answer (score 1):

The parent directory (`/home/shelly/cod4server/server`) and its files are all read-only for any user except `shellycod4`.  The group permission is the middle portion and has no `w` that would allow write access.

If, as `root` or `shellycod4`, you `chmod g+w /home/shelly/cod4server/server`, then `shelly`, who is part of the `shellycod4` group, will be able to write new files to it (among other things).

Similarly, if you want to make `/home/shelly/cod4server/server/img.png` writable by users of the same group, you woudl `chmod g+w /home/shelly/cod4server/server/img.png`.  If you wish to give write access to anyone that is not the owner or in the file's group, you could `chmod o+w /home/shelly/cod4server/server/img.png`.

This answer is a really quick overview to answer your question directly, but you should probably look for tutorials on Linux permissions to better understand it.